# General case of the 24-challenge problem

Tags: algorithm, ruby

I'm working on an algorithm to solve the [24-challenge game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game). The basic idea is to combine positive integers using arithmetic operators to produce an expression that evaluates to exactly 24. For instance, `(9 - 3) * (2 + 2) = 24`. My current implementation is functional (delivers responses in less than 15 seconds) with seven or fewer inputs. I think there is plenty room for optimization - especially when trying to consider every order-of-operations to apply to a permutation of the inputs. I have included my code below. Any tips/tricks/suggestions much appreciated!

```
# usage:
# irb> Solver.solve(8, 8, 3, 3)

require 'set'

class Solver

    def initialize(nums)
        @nums = nums
        @arity = nums.size
        @ops = initialize_functions
        @op_orders = op_orders(@ops.keys, @arity - 1)
        @solutions = Set.new

        @SOLUTION = 24.0
        @MAX_SOLUTIONS = 10
        @TOLERANCE = 0.000001
    end

    def solve
        # iterate over all unique permutations of given numbers
        @nums.permutation.to_a.uniq do |ordered_nums|
            # iterate over all permutations of the operators
            @op_orders.each do |ops|
                procs = ops.map{|op_name| @ops[op_name][:proc]}
                symbols = ops.map{|op_name| @ops[op_name][:symbol]}
                # iterate over all possible orders of operations
                (0...ops.size).entries.permutation do |order_of_ops|
                    ordered_nums_copy = ordered_nums.clone
                    root = nil
                    order_of_ops.each do |op_index|
                        proc = procs[op_index]
                        sym = symbols[op_index]
                        tree = BinaryTree.new(proc, sym, ordered_nums_copy[op_index], ordered_nums_copy[op_index + 1])
                        old_ref1, ordered_nums_copy[op_index] = ordered_nums_copy[op_index], tree
                        old_ref2, ordered_nums_copy[op_index + 1] = ordered_nums_copy[op_index + 1], tree
                        ordered_nums_copy.each_with_index do |ref, index|
                            if (ref.is_a? BinaryTree) && [old_ref1, old_ref2].include?(ref)
                                ordered_nums_copy[index] = tree
                            end
                        end
                        root = tree
                    end
                    answer = root.calc
                    if is_solution?(answer)
                        # puts "solution: #{root}"
                        @solutions << root.to_s
                        if @solutions.size >= @MAX_SOLUTIONS
                            return @solutions
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        return @solutions
    end

    private

    def initialize_functions
        add = Proc.new{|n, m| n + m}
        subtract = Proc.new{|n, m| n - m}
        multiply = Proc.new{|n, m| n * m}
        divide = Proc.new{|n, m| n.to_f / m}
        exponent = Proc.new{|n, m| n ** m}

        return {
            add: {
                proc: add,
                symbol: '+'
            },
            subtract: {
                proc: subtract,
                symbol: '-'
            },
            multiply: {
                proc: multiply,
                symbol: '*'
            },
            divide: {
                proc: divide,
                symbol: '/'
            }
            # exponent: {
            #   proc: exponent,
            #   symbol: '^'
            # }
        }
    end

    def is_solution?(solution)
        return (@SOLUTION - solution.to_f).abs < @TOLERANCE
    rescue
        false
    end

    def op_orders(ops, num_to_choose)
        results = []
        radix = ops.size
        min = 0
        max = ((ops.size - 1).to_s * num_to_choose).to_i(radix)
        (min..max).each do |num|
            results << ("0" * num_to_choose + num.to_s(radix)).slice(num_to_choose * -1, num_to_choose).split('').map{|i| ops[i.to_i]}
        end
        return results
    end

    def self.solve(*nums)
        Solver.new(nums).solve
    end
end

class BinaryTree
    attr_accessor :left, :right, :proc, :sym
    def initialize(proc = nil, sym = nil, left = nil, right = nil)
        self.proc, self.sym, self.left, self.right = proc, sym, left, right
    end
    def calc
        left_operand = (left.is_a? BinaryTree) ? left.calc : left.to_f
        right_operand = (right.is_a? BinaryTree) ? right.calc : right.to_f
        return proc.call(left_operand, right_operand)
    end
    def to_s
        return "(#{left.to_s} #{sym} #{right.to_s})"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @SOLUTION = 24.0
    @MAX_SOLUTIONS = 10
    @TOLERANCE = 0.000001
```

I guess those uppercase names are used to denote constants, you can also use class constants for that.

```
    # iterate over all unique permutations of given numbers
    @nums.permutation.to_a.uniq do |ordered_nums|
```

A "unique permutation" is a "combination", you have a [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) for that.

```
                ordered_nums_copy = ordered_nums.clone
                root = nil
                order_of_ops.each do |op_index|
```

An advice: when dealing when mathematical/logic problems, use [functional programming](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming). No clones, eachs, `<<`, `update`', all that imperative stuff. Define *what* values are instead of *how* you calculate them. Strive for declarative programming.

```
    add = Proc.new{|n, m| n + m}
    subtract = Proc.new{|n, m| n - m}
    multiply = Proc.new{|n, m| n * m}
    divide = Proc.new{|n, m| n.to_f / m}
    exponent = Proc.new{|n, m| n ** m}
```

Those procs are unnecessary, use the symbol and `send` when needed. By the way, is this to_f correct? I though the game allowed only integer division.

```
    return {
```

It's not idiomatic to use `return` for the last expression of a block/method.

```
def is_solution?(solution)
    return (@SOLUTION - solution.to_f).abs < @TOLERANCE
rescue
    false
end
```

That's not good practice, exceptions are used for excepcional situations, not to get out of algorithms. Note that lazy enumerators are a nice way to isolate the generation of solutions of the filtering/stopping condition. But in any case you must deal with it in another way.

By the way, this is very similar to the numbers round of [Countdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29#Numbers_round), isn't it? By that name you surely will find implementations in Ruby and other languages. Some time ago I wrote [this one](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/source/browse/trunk/functional/presentation/src/cifras/cifras5.rb?r=687) (now I'd change some things, but it may server as inspiration).